# connected manifolds are path connected

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, connectedness

> prove every connected manifold is path connected manifold .
>
> **my thought:**
>
> **connected space :** Let $ X$  be a topological space. A separation of $ X $ is a pair $U, V$ of disjoint 
>   nonempty open subsets of $ X $ whose union is $X$. The space $ X $ is said to be connected 
>   if there does not exist a separation of  $X$ .
>
> **Components:** Given  $X$ , define an equivalence relation on $X$ by setting x~y if there 
>   is a connected subspace of $X$  containing both $ x$  and $ y$ . The equivalence classes are 
>   called the components (or the "connected components") of $ X$.
>
> **Path Component:** I define another equivalence relation on the space $ X$  by defining x ~ у 
>   if there is a path in $ X$  from $ x$  to $ y$ . The equivalence classes are called the path components of $ X$ .
>
> **Theorem  :** The path components of $ X$  are path connected disjoint subspaces 
>   of $X$  whose union is $X$ , such that each nonempty path connected subspace of $X$  intersects only one of them.
>
> *thank you so much*

Comment: There is a result that every connected and locally path-connected space is path connected. Can you show that the manifold is locally path-connected?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Let $x\in X$. Consider $U:=\{y\in X\mathop{|}\text{there is a path from $x$ to $y$}\}$. So $U$ is nonempty: $x\in U$. Claim: $U$ and $U^c:=X\smallsetminus U$ both are open. To prove this use the fact that given any point $z\in X$ there is a neighbourhood of $z$ which is homeomorphic to an open ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$. The homeomorphic image of a path connected set is path connected, so $U$ and $U^c$ both are open but $U \cup U^c = X$ which implies that $U=X$ since $U$ is nonempty.

Comment: How exactly is concluded that $U$ and $U^c$ are open? I do not see it. Thanks.

Comment: @Cornman, if every $z\in X$ belongs to some path-connected open, then every  $z\in U$ belongs to a path-connected open fully included in $U$ (otherwise it would connect some $y\in U^c$ to $z$ through a path, contradiction), and for the same reason every $y\in U^c$ belongs to a (path-connected) open fully contained in $U^c$. Thus $U$ and $U^c$ are open by definition.

Answer (score 5):

path connected sets are also connected, conversely is not always true (there is a famous counterexample which shows this fact). However a necessary condition To make the converse of the previous  statement possible is that the connected sets are required to be locally Euclidean. So a topological manifold, by definition is also a locally Euclidean space, if you can prove the previous statement you can get the answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Given our manifold M is connected, let $x, y \in M$ be arbitrary point.

Since for any $x$ there is an open set $U_x \cong \mathbb{R}^n$ for which  $x$ is contained, let $C_x$ denote the path component of $x$. If $y$ is contained then we are done. However, if not then as then let $\bigcup_{x \in C_x}U_x =C_x $ which is open.

$M$ is the union of path connected components, by previous reasoning all path connected components are open. Thus this implies that $M$ is disconnected  contradicting our hypothesis $y \notin M$. Therefore, $M$ is path connected.

Conversely, path connectednesss implies connectedness as required.

Proving that Manifold is connected if and only it is path connected.