# $a^n=0\,\Rightarrow\, X-a\mid X^n$ (nilpotent Factor Theorem)

Tags: commutative-algebra

Proposition 1.6 in A. Kleiman *A Term of Commutative Algebra* says that if $R$ is a ring and $a \in R$, then the map $\pi:R[X]\rightarrow R$ given by $\pi(X) = a$ has kernel generated by $(X-a)$ and $R[X]/(X-a)$ is isomorphic to $R$. But if $a$ is nilpotent, say $a^n = 0$, then $\pi(X^n) = a^n = 0$ so $X^n \in \operatorname{Ker}(\pi)$, but $X^n \notin \langle X-a\rangle$ (the ideal generated by $X-a$).

Am I missing something? Certainly, the proposition is true if $R$ is an integral domain.

Comment: TeX note: please use $\operatorname{Ker}$ `\operatorname{Ker}` (or `\DeclareMathOperator\Ker{Ker}` and then just `\Ker` if it's something you'll use frequently) in place of just $Ker$, and $\langle X - a\rangle$ `\langle X - a\rangle` in place of $<X - a>$.  For the latter, note the difference in spacing between $X^n \notin \langle X - a\rangle$ (`X^n \notin \langle X - a\rangle`)—correct spacing, although the statement is incorrect, as @DaveBenson [explained](https://mathoverflow.net/a/457210)—and $X^n \notin <X - a>$ `X^n \notin <X - a>`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice to begin with, this is not research level maths, and so it is not suitable on MathOverflow...

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457209/error-in-altman-kleiman-a-term-of-commutative-algebra#comment1184224_457209), that is true but, I think, orthogonal to my comment.  (I did not answer the question.)  Hopefully this will be migrated to MathSE, and, when it is there, it will still be good for the TeX to be correct.

Comment: @LSpice what I meant is that the expectation of LaTeX proficiency on MO and MSE is clearly very different, and so I was confused by the fact that it were the TeXnical matters that you prioritised...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you're missing something. It's that $$X^n=X^n-a^n=(X-a)(X^{n-1}+aX^{n-2}+\dots+a^{n-2}X+a^{n-1})$$ is in the ideal generated by $X-a$.

Comment: Thank you. Duh! :) How did I miss that?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, but didn't like to mention it out of politeness. At least the question was properly migrated, and belongs quite comfortably here.

Comment: @rwilsker We don't need the quotient: $\,a\,$ is a root of $\,x^n\Rightarrow x-a\mid x^n\,$ in $R[x]\,$ by the [Factor Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/738715/242).

Answer (score 3):

$\,a^n\!=\!0\,\Rightarrow\, a\,$ is a root of $\,x^n\Rightarrow x-a\mid x^n\,$ in $R[x]\:\!$ by FT= [Factor Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/738715/242). $\ \bf\small QED$

**Remark** $ $ This method is  worth explicit emphasis since it seems many students overlook that FT applies here.  Generally FT $\Rightarrow x-a\mid f(x)-f(a)\,$ (we can compute the quotient from that if need be as in Dave's answer, but we *don't* need it here). This is also closely related to inverting a unit + nilpotent (by simpler multiples - analogous to rationalizing a denominator), see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3225783/242).